# Finding all vertices, extremal rays, and extremal lines of a polyhedron

Tags: optimization, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

The following problem was given to me by a friend .

> Find all vertices, extremal rays, and extremal lines of the following polyhedron. $$ P = \left\{ x ∈ \Bbb R^3 : 2x_1 − x_2 \ge 2, x_1 + x_2 \ge 1, −x_1 + x_2 \ge 2, x_i \ge 1, i = 1, \dots , 3 \right\} $$ Prove that you have really found all vertices, extremal rays and extremal lines.

---

I can't for the life of me figure out what to do. I am just completely lost and would be extremely grateful if someone could help so I can to these problems with no issue in the future.

I got $(1,0,0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(0,2,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Set $x_3=1$ then solve three systems of two linear equations to find $x_1, x_2$ of three vertices (three equations can be split into three pairs). The last vertex will be $(1,1,1)$. Once you found vertices, the rest is easy.

Comment: Let me suggest you take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on how to [avoid "I am just completely lost" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Not sure if I did it correctly but I got (1,0,0) (0,5, 0,5, 0) (0,1,0)?

Comment: [Vertex enumeration problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem)

Comment: I read it, but still don't understand if my edit is correct or not

Comment: [Some algorithmic problems in polytope theory](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~pfetsch/Publications/polycomplex.pdf) [PDF]

Comment: Then try the following.  You have $6$ inequalities in $3$ variables.  Randomly pick $3$ inequalities from the set of $6$ inequalities and replace $\leq$ or $\geq$ with $=$, thereby obtaining a system of $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns, whose solution, when it exists, is either a point, a line or a plane.  Do it for all $\binom{6}{3}$ choices.  Better use a computer.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do, I edited my answers in the question

Comment: Windows? What does that have to do with if my answers were correct or not?

Comment: In the question itself, explain how you obtained those points.  If you wrote code, embed the code using the `{}` button.